# Proper position for my colorbar in an AxesGrid collocation

Tags: python, matplotlib, multiple-axes

[image]

The figure above was produced by

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.axes_grid1 import AxesGrid

mat = [[1,2],[3,4]]
fig = plt.figure()
grid = AxesGrid(fig, 111, nrows_ncols=(1,3),
       axes_pad=0.2, share_all=False, label_mode='L',
       cbar_location="bottom", cbar_mode="single")
for ax in grid.axes_all: im = ax.imshow(mat)
# plt.colorbar(im, cax=??)
plt.show()
```

To complete the job, I'd like to draw a colorbar, *probably* using the Axes at the bottom of the figure (but I'm not sure that using `cax=...` is what I need),

HOWEVER

I don't know how to recover the bottom Axes from `grid`.

After `dir(grid)`, I've tried to specify `ax=grid.cb_axes` but the result is amendable

[image]

What must be done to have everything in its right place?

Comment: `plt.colorbar(im, cax=grid.cbar_axes[0], orientation='horizontal')` seems to work here.

Comment: @JohanC I confirm your finding, Now, If I could find why it works with `cax=grid.cbar_axes[0]` but silently fails with `cax=grid.cbar_axes[1]`. Nevertheless, if you'd be pleased to post this as an answer...

Comment: I'm not sure what's happening. With `cbar_mode="single"` it seems the first colorbar is changed to cover the desired region and the two other seem to be invisible.  Also, the orientation of the colorbar isn't set automatically to horizontal.  Feel free to answer your own question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another (shorter) way is using `grid.cbar_axes[0].colorbar(im)`:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.axes_grid1 import AxesGrid

mat = [[1,2],[3,4]]
fig = plt.figure()
grid = AxesGrid(fig, 111, nrows_ncols=(1,3),
       axes_pad=0.2, share_all=False, label_mode='L',
       cbar_location="bottom", cbar_mode="single")
for ax in grid.axes_all: im = ax.imshow(mat)
grid.cbar_axes[0].colorbar(im)
```

[image]

As JohanC already stated in the comment, with `cbar_mode="single"`, [all but the first `cbar_axes` are set invisible](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/blob/b3bd929cf07ea35479fded8f739126ccc39edd6d/lib/mpl_toolkits/axes_grid1/axes_grid.py#L452-L455):

```
    for i in range(self.ngrids):
        self.cbar_axes[i].set_visible(False)
    self.cbar_axes[0].set_axes_locator(locator)
    self.cbar_axes[0].set_visible(True)
```